# How to Translate Postgres query to Entity Framework Where Clause

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

How can I translate the following Postgresql query to the Entity Framework Core Where clause?

```
select title from some_table where title ~ '[^[:ascii:]]';
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~` is an operator for pattern matching using regular expressions. Npgsql EF Core provider automatically translates .NET's [`Regex.IsMatch`](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/translations.html#string-functions) so you can just try using it:

```cs
context.SomeTable
    .Where(t => Regex.IsMatch(t.Title, "[^[:ascii:]]"))
    ...
```